# Does No Land Beyond produce sniper scope glint in PvP?

Tags: destiny

Just picked up this weapon from Xur, really enjoying using it but wondering if it produces the sniper scope glint in PvP. Hoping it doesn't, and realistically it shouldn't as there is no glass scope on the weapon, just iron sights.

Comment: It does, and in my opinion the rate of fire is not viable in pvp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does have the red scope glint that regular sniper rifles have.

[Here](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2q9rgy/if_no_land_beyond_is_iron_sighted_why_does_it/) are some other players discussing the issue. [Here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/704532-destiny/70961720) is another discussion.  I've also witnessed it first hand in PvP deaths by the few bold players that run it as their primary. I tried to find an image/video but nothing came up at first search.

As an aside, you can see sniper glint in PvE as well.  If you want to test this out for NLB or any other sniper in the future, you can load up patrol with a friend and test it out.